# Azure virtual machine URL Redirect in DNS settings

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, url

I have a Linux VM setup in Azure and have a DNS Zone CNAME record set as per:

```
NAME    TYPE    TTTL    VALUE
www     CNAME   60      myapp.azurecouldaddress.com
```

I can't use an A name record for the root (non www) doamin as I am not using a static IP.

I am trying to set up a permanent URL Redirect for myapp.com to point to www.myapp.com. In the azure docs here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-custom-domain-name

It mentions:

```
"If you want to direct traffic from subdomains, such as *.contoso.com, to your cloudapp.net address, you can configure a URL Redirect or URL Forward entry in your DNS settings"
```

But where can I do this?, I cant find a reference to 'URL Redirect' or 'URL Forward' anywhere on the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com)

Comment: You could configure it on your domain provider not Azure portal. Here is a good link about this http://bretstateham.com/10-easy-steps-to-azure-web-site-custom-domains/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But where can I do this?, I cant find a reference to 'URL Redirect' or
>   'URL Forward' anywhere on the Azure portal?

You could configure it on your DNS provider. Here is a good [link](http://bretstateham.com/10-easy-steps-to-azure-web-site-custom-domains/) about this.